# Why Elastic Beanstalk stop working?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am completely new to the AWS and I have successfully deployed my Java program to Elastic Beanstalk.
First 30 minutes or sometimes even 6 hours it's working pretty fine.

But later I always got a message:
"Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 1 out of 1 instances are impacted. See instance health for details."
or
"Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx."

And my site stop working and when I try to access it through my browser it's says
  "Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server"

If I run my program on my computer its work fine without errors. So I think the problem is in my AWS Environment.
I am using free t2.micro instance - does it have some limits for processing power in hour or something like that?
If it's not - how can I find whats wrong is going on with my Environment or Instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http 5xx error is coming from your application server and is most probably not AWS issue.. Please check server logs of your server.

Yes every server ( micro or the biggest server in this world ) has some limits; but I don't think thats the problem in your case..

Comment: Thanks. Where can I found this logs and what I need to find in them?

Comment: As you said its a java program; it might be hosted on some application server like tomcat right ? so u need to see that server logs

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), `t2.micro` instances only have 1GB of RAM. I suspect that your application is consuming more than that after some amount of time. As @Deepak suggested, your application logs should illuminate the problem.

All `t2` instances are [Burstable Performance Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#burst), which means that after a sustained period of load, their performance will drop off significantly. However, that alone shouldn't be causing your 5xx errors.